Callables of the form [\"Swift_Message\", \"Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage::__construct\"] are deprecated
                ` $pdf = new Pdf([
                    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
                    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
                    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
                    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_STRING,
                 ]);
                $pdf->content = $this->renderPartial('finance', [
                    'cleanData' => $cleanData,
                    'driver' => $driver,
                    'totalWorkingHour' => $totalWorkingHour,
                    'fdate' => $fdate,
                    'tdate' => $tdate
                ]);
                $pdfContent = $pdf->render();

                $message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setFrom('noreply@test.com')
                    ->setTo($email)
                    ->setSubject($driver . ' Summary')
                    ->setTextBody("Please find as attached the requested report.")
                    ->attachContent($pdfContent, [
                        'fileName' => 'Summary.pdf',
                        'contentType' => 'application/pdf'
                    ]);

                if (!$message->send()) {
                    throw new \Exception('Failed to send email');
                }`

i'm having trouble with sending the pdf it gives me
"Callables of the form ["Swift_Message", "Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage::__construct"] are deprecated"
I don't want to save the file before attaching it to the email. How can i solve the problem?

Is it just a deprecation warning or does it stop your process ? Because if it's just a warning, swift mailer itself is deprecated since 2021 as development stopped (replaced by symfony/mailer)

it's not sending the email

I would suggest migrating to yiisoft/yii2-symfonymailer instead of yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer. As Dylan KAS mentioned swift mailer has been abandoned and it's not updated to work on newer php versions. The migration should only require changes in configuration.

Can you sahre more details about the problem? Where is that callable called in your code? And is this problem really related to [tag:pdf]?
